# Integrating Shiny with Leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I'm trying to visualise all the trees present in Central Melbourne. 
The dataset I'm using is available here - [Urban Forest Data](https://data.melbourne.vic.gov.au/Environment/Melbourne-s-Urban-Forest-Tree-data/fp38-wiyy)

I'm successful in plotting all the trees present in the dataset and also colour coded them according to their Life Expectancy.

I was wondering on how I can integrate this with Shiny so that I can filter the plot by the column "Precinct". That is, when I select "CBD", it should plot only trees in that area. My code so far and a screenshot of the working plot is as below:

**Code:**

```
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
td <- read.csv("treedata.csv", header = TRUE)

pal <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "RdYlGn",
  domain = td$LifeExpectencyValue
)

leaflet(td) %>% addTiles(
  urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
  attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
) %>% addCircleMarkers(radius= 5,fillOpacity = 0.5, stroke = FALSE,color=~pal(LifeExpectencyValue),
                                                popup=paste("Name:", td$CommonName, "<br>", "Years Left:", td$LifeExpectency, "<br>", "Genus:", td$Genus)

) %>% addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~LifeExpectencyValue, opacity = 1, title = "Life Expectancy")
```

Screenshot of the plot:
[image]

I'm new to Shiny so any help here is deeply appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

**Shiny Code Tried:**

```
require(rCharts)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectInput("precinct",
              label="Precinct",
              choices = sort(td$Precinct),
              selected = "CBD"),
  plotOutput("treedat") #Giving an input name and listing out types to choose in the Shiny app
)

server <- function(input, output){

  output$treedat <- renderLeaflet({
    PRECINCT = input$precinct
    precinct = subset(td, precinct == PRECINCT)
    td2 <- leaflet(td) %>% addTiles(
      urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
    ) %>% addCircleMarkers(radius= 5,fillOpacity = 0.5, stroke = FALSE,color=~pal(LifeExpectencyValue),
                           popup=paste("Name:", td$CommonName, "<br>", "Years Left:", td$LifeExpectency, "<br>", "Genus:", td$Genus)

    ) %>% addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~LifeExpectencyValue, opacity = 1, title = "Life Expectency")
    return(td2)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Getting an error saying object 'Precinct' not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of points

1. You are using `leaflet` in your code, but `rCharts` in your app. Here I'm just using `leaflet` in the shiny app. (And, as far as I'm aware `rCharts` isn't yet on CRAN?)
2. The choices that populate your drop-down are based on the data. Therefore, I've moved the `selectInput` into the server using `renderUI/UIOutput`. I also use `as.chacter` around the choices so you see the character representation, rather than the `factor` levels

I've also removed the code that colours the trees as there is no column called **LifeExpectancy** in the raw data (I'm assuming you've cleand the column headings somewhere?)

And lastly, a couple of small changes to how you subset your data and you're good to go.

```
library(leaflet)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("precinct"),
  leafletOutput("treedat") #Giving an input name and listing out types to choose in the Shiny app
)

server <- function(input, output){

  # td <- read.csv("~/Desktop/Melbourne_s_Urban_Forest_Tree_data.csv", header = T)

  output$precinct <- renderUI({

    choices <- as.character(unique(td$Precinct))  
    choices <- c('All', choices)
    selectInput(inputId = "precinct", label = "Precinct", choices = choices, selected = "CBD")

  })


  output$treedat <- renderLeaflet({

    ## get the choice from teh drop-down box
    PRECINCT = input$precinct

    ## supbset the data based on the choice
    if(PRECINCT != 'All'){
        td2 <- td[td$Precinct == PRECINCT, ]
    }else{
        td2 <- td
    }
    ## plot the subsetted ata
    td2 <- leaflet(td2) %>% addTiles(
      urlTemplate = 'http://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/dark_all/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
      attribution='Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a> &mdash; Map data &copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>') %>% 
      addCircleMarkers(radius= 5,fillOpacity = 0.5, stroke = FALSE)
    return(td2)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Always had a doubt about Leaflet and rCharts working together. Just a thought on top of this, how do I add an "All" option in the dropdown so that it plots all areas?

Comment: Works great now! Just what I wanted! Thanks

Comment: Is there a way that I can get the shiny input selection widget below the map plot?

Comment: Swap the order of the lines in the `ui`

Comment: Depends how  many trees you have, it could be time consuming if you have to redraw whole map every time. You can create group depending on precinct, then call functions  `showGroup` and `hideGroup` to update your maps.

Comment: If you want a full screen map and selective input at the bottom, you can use the `absolutePanel`. See example here: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/superzip-example.html

Comment: Thank you for your inputs guys!

Comment: @Bangyou I couldn't find the showGroup and hideGroup functions in the link you gave me? Any inputs on that?

Comment: @Symbolix I'm getting an error saying "Argument is of length zero" when I run shiny but it eventually plots it. Any ideas?

Comment: it usually displays that message while the data is loading. Put a `if(is.null(td)) return()` as the first line inside the `renderLeaflet` function and see if that helps.

Comment: @Symbolix I added the code like this `output$treedat <- renderLeaflet({
    if(is.null(td))
      return()
    ## get the choice from teh drop-down box
    PRECINCT = input$precinct
    
    ## supbset the data based on the choice
    if(PRECINCT != 'All'){
      td2 <- td[td$Precinct == PRECINCT, ]
    }else{
      td2 <- td
    }` but it still gives me the same message.

Comment: @ArvindSuryanarayana You  may need to install the developing version of leaflet package. Try `devtools::install_github('rstudio/leaflet')`. If you still cannot find it, try my fork: `devtools::install_github('byzheng/leaflet')`.